# Bunch of errors and IDK why

Tags: java

I am a new coder, and have no clue why im getting a bunch of errors in this program im trying to make? can someone show me where I went wrong? I think im having issues with figuring out constructors and classes. I think my methods are correctly formatted, but I may be wrong.

```
public class Bank 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   
        private double balance;
        private String name;
        private int pin;
            
        public void Bank(double balance, String name, int pin)
        {
            this.balance = balance;
            this.name = name;
            this.pin = pin;
        }
        
            
        public String withdraw(double amount)
        {
            if(balance - amount >= 0)
            {
                double val = (double)(balance - amount);
                String value = String.valueOf(val);
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return " insufficient funds";
            }
        }
        
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        
        public int getPin()
        {
            return pin;
        }
    //commented out
    //System.out.println("Succesfully excecuted. ");
            
    }
```

}

Comment: What are the bunch of errors you are getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Illegal modifier for parameter balance; only final is permitted
 Illegal modifier for parameter name; only final is permitted
 Illegal modifier for parameter pin; only final is permitted
 Syntax error on token "void", record expected
 void is an invalid type for the variable Bank
 Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token
 Syntax error, insert "}" to complete RecordBody

 at Bank.main(Bank.java:10)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/; and keep in mind that this is *not a discussion forum*. As such, we are not interested in your level of experience, or your confusion with the problem. We are interested in a *specific, clearly asked* question, which results after your own attempt to diagnose the problem. Also, please show [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error messages, *in the question itself*.

Comment: In your own words: what does `public static void main(String[] args) ` *mean*? What is its purpose, and how should it be used? In your own words, what do all the `{` and `}` do within a Java program? Do you see an issue? Also: *what is actually supposed to happen* when you run the code? It is all well and good to explain some methods for creating and using instances of the `Bank` class, but none of that matters unless the code actually *creates and uses instances*.

Comment: The code is still a work in progress, Im just trying to get it to the point where there are no errors before I continue to code. My vision for the program is to basically have a banking system where the person enters how much money they want to withdraw, and enter their pin and name and it will withdraw the money from their account and update the user with their current balance.                   TLDR: ATM Machine

Answer (score 1):

You are keeping your instance variables, constructor and other method inside the main method. You need to keep them outside the main block but inside the class. You can call a method from another method but you cannot declare a method inside another method.

```
public class Bank 
{
     private double balance;
     private String name;
     private int pin;
     
     public void Bank(double balance, String name, int pin)
     {
         this.balance = balance;
         this.name = name;
         this.pin = pin;
     }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
  // create object and perform operation
         
    //commented out
    //System.out.println("Succesfully excecuted. ");
            
    }
    public String withdraw(double amount)
    {
        if(balance - amount >= 0)
        {
            double val = (double)(balance - amount);
            String value = String.valueOf(val);
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            return " insufficient funds";
        }
    }
    
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getPin()
    {
        return pin;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok.  I kinda think I know what youre saying, but am also lost at the same time. Am I supposed to rearrange the public static void to be at the top?

Comment: @SamizzstuVeliu no, the order of main does not matter( it can be on top, bottom , middle) but you have to ensure that the other methods that you have declared ( getName(), getPin() and constructor ) should not be inside the main method. just compare your posted code with my code

Comment: Okay, I think I kind of understand now (correct me if im wrong). But basically the instance variables and constructor cant be in the public static void. The public static void is where the methods go? Is that correct or am I still off?

Comment: your instance variables and constructor go inside the class( in your case, Bank) but outside any method( that includes main method ) . public static void -> are just access modifiers , the name of the method is main ( this is what jvm looks for when running the program ) . even your methods don't go inside the main method , you only call the methods from your main method , and don't declare it ( public int getPin() {return pin}) is called declaration, 
calling the method is something like int res = getPin(); 
i know too many technical terms , but i hope i was able to answer your question

Comment: okay, thanks for the help; hopefully I get a hang of it one day lmfao.

Comment: @SamizzstuVeliu tell me what is not clear yet .i can explain in simpler terms also

Comment: My main question that I have is do I need to have two separate files to make this code operate properly? That is the solution that I am seeing other people use when coding in java, but I don't know if I actually need to have two separate files. From what im seeing, they are putting the public static void in a different files, and creating a new object in that file and then calling the methods there. Do you think that would work for my program?

Comment: nvm, I finally figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Variable with modifiers are defined at class level not a method level. Paste this code outside the main method and you're good to go.
Also this is my first answer here :)